# I´m using bootstrap modal with ajax but I don´t work

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, slim

I´ve got a form, with several fields, when I push about click event button execute:

```
 $("#box-modal").on("shown",function(event)
   {
       $("button#add-cart").click(function(e)
       {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: '/lineorder/addCart/'+valueidproduct,
                        data: $("#form-product").serialize()
                    });
                }
```

I get the response network

```
http://localhost:8080/lineorder/addCart/2
type: POST
status: 200 OK
```

My call go to the route of slim /lineorder/addCart/2

```
$app->post('/lineorder/addCart/:id',function($id) use($app)
{
   var_dump("hi");die();

   if(isset($_POST['add-cart'])) 
   {
       $nombre = $app->request()->post('inputnombre');
       var_dump($nombre);die();

   }
}
```

How I cand Try the variable inside my route with var_dump(), for view it´s work not?
but I do var_dump("hi"); and don´t appear any response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be like this.You can just alert to check or write to the document using javascript

```
 $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: '/lineorder/addCart/'+valueidproduct,
          data: $("#form-product").serialize()
         }).done(function(response){
             alert(response) 
  });
```

Comment: So I can not see any var_dump without invoke function done. In my route slim?

Comment: it's running in the background.To see the output you have to get back to your javascript, right?